# How can I use libcurl to parse through a webpage line-by-line?

Tags: c, libcurl

Ok, so I'm building this program in C for a Linux system. I need to be able to retrieve the content of a URL, and then read it line-by-line so I can do my own custom parsing on it.

Now, what's very important to me is speed, meaning I'd really like to do this without saving the entire thing to a file, then reading the file (since, for example, there may be content on the first line of the file that means I don't need to read the rest of it).

Also very important is that it is thread-safe. I tried using the code here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/fopen.html but it uses global variables that make it impossible to safely multithread.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to retrieve the data for a page, it's fairly easy to use the socket API directly. There are also quite a few libraries around that make it a bit easier still. Unfortunately, you haven't said what system you want this for so it's hard to recommend which library you probably want (Windows demands a bit of special code to startup/shut down Winsock that isn't necessary and won't compile or link on almost any other system).

Comment: It's for Linux (original question edited). Any recommendations for libraries?

Comment: Instead of a library, how about source code for a complete program: http://coding.debuntu.org/c-linux-socket-programming-tcp-simple-http-client

Comment: Implementing a full-fledged and compliant URL client (the question doesn't even say which protocol it is for) is A LOT OF WORK and would re-invent existing wheels.

Comment: @Daniel: Perhaps you could learn how to read. You don't need a "full-fledged and compliant URL client" to "retrieve the content of **a** URL." Your downvote is a marginally better than those that don't bother trying to explain their reasoning at all, but that's about the best that can be said for it.

Comment: The "content of a URL" means that you need to download a piece of a file identified by a protocol as the URL specifies. To do that, you need to write code to handle the specific protocol. We don't know which protocol(s). I can't see how your answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Examples are just that: examples. If they work slightly wrong, then fix it to work better.

I would guess that you're better off starting with another example, perhaps this getinemory.c:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html

libcurl delivers data "chunk by chunk" and not line by line, so your application needs to figure out when you have enough data and you can then tell libcurl to stop transferring.

Comment: Did you bother reading the question at all? He specifically says he already tried cURL and that it *won't work* for him!

Comment: He complained about a specific libcurl example, yes, and I explained how that was just an example and that there even are other examples that do it "right"